# How can I print the mean of a pandas dataframe columns in a horizontal fashion?

Tags: python, pandas

`print(df.mean(axis=0))` returns an output which is something like this

```
x           -100.482156
y             -0.081388
z             -0.090348
....
```

But what I want is something that looks like this (basically a transpose of what was printed by default)

```
x   y      z  
-100.482156 -0.081388 -0.090348
```

Comment: `df.mean(axis=0).T` to transpose your dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

Pandas returns the mean as a series, so you first need to convert it to a data frame using df.to_frame(), then you can transpose it.
`df_avg=df_original.mean(axis=0).to_frame().transpose()`

Where df_original is the df you’re taking the average of.